# Proving statements about ceiling and floor functions.

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, inequality, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Prove or disprove the statements below.

(a) For all positive real numbers x and y, $\lfloor x \cdot y\rfloor  ≤ \lfloor x\rfloor \cdot \lfloor y\rfloor $.

(b) For all positive real numbers x and y, $ \lceil x \cdot y\rceil ≤ \lceil x\rceil\cdot  \lceil y\rceil $ .

---

The brackets were not covered in my class and I can't seem to find them on google so I can't even start the problem as I can't figure out their meanings...

Comment: So $bxc=\lfloor x\rfloor$?

Comment: That would be the floor function

Comment: The d and e would be the ceiling function

Comment: Yes, floor and ceiling.

Comment: sorry guys I had no idea what it was. I couldn't even figured out its name. Ill try to google it. it wouldn't copy from pdf ( it usuall does)

Comment: The "floor function," also known as the "greatest integer function," basically chops off the decimal part of a number. For example, $\lfloor3.142\rfloor=3$, $\lfloor2.718\rfloor=2$, $\lfloor1.618\rfloor=1$, $\lfloor6\rfloor=6$, etc. It's called the "greatest integer function," because $\lfloor x\rfloor$ can be defined as "the greatest integer $k$ such that $k\le x$." It's also often called the "integer part." The part that was chopped off is called the "fractional part," and is sometimes denoted by $\{x\}$. Thus, $\{3.141\}=0.141$, $\{1.234\}=0.234$, $\{6\}=0$, etc.

Comment: It's something you can google, though. @Marc-AndreLeclair

Comment: not with the sign b and e, it led me to assignments ( and mine as the 3rd one). Don't worry I know how to google things, at least :). Anyway I did after someone mentionned ceiling and floor functions!

Comment: The "ceiling function" basically rounds up (as opposed to the floor function, which rounds down). For example, $\lceil3.142\rceil=4$, $\lceil2.718\rceil=3$, $\lceil1.618\rceil=2$, $\lceil6\rceil=6$, etc. Note that, _if $k$ is an integer, then $\lfloor k\rfloor=\lceil k\rceil$!_ If $k$ isn't an integer, than $\lfloor k\rfloor+1=\lceil k\rceil$. The ceiling function can be defined as "the smallest integer $k$ such that $k\ge x$."

Comment: It gets annoying with negative numbers. $\lfloor-2.7\rfloor=-3$, even though it _looks_ like $-2$ should be the integer part. This can be explained by going back to the definition: "the greatest integer $k$ such that $k\le x$." Since $-3<-2.7<-2$, the floor of $-2.7$ is $\lfloor-2.7\rfloor=-3$, and the ceiling is $\lceil-2.7\rceil=-2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$a)$ is false (counter-example $(x,y)=(1.5,1.5)$).

$b)$ is true. Let $x=x_1-r_1,y=y_1-r_2, (x_1,y_1\in\mathbb Z^+), 0\le r_1,r_2< 1$.

$$\lceil xy\rceil=\lceil x_1y_1-r_2x_1-r_1y_1+r_1r_2\rceil\le \lceil x_1y_1 -r_1-r_2+r_1r_2\rceil\le \lceil x_1y_1\rceil=x_1y_1$$

This used $r_1+r_2\ge 2\sqrt{r_1r_2}\ge r_1r_2$.

Comment: sorry but I'm completely lost with what just happened. I just "learned" what floor and ceiling functions are so excuse me if I got this wrong. For the first one, how can you use a counter example of 1.5 if you don't know the function? I mean 1.5 * 1.5 would give you 3, and on the other side it would give you 1? is that how you went about it?

Comment: And for b), how did you come to use r1 and r2? also why would it be important to highlight the fact that x1 and y1 are part of the positive integer set?  Are you doing so to make x and y rational numbers?

Comment: @Marc-AndreLeclair $\lfloor 1.5\cdot 1.5\rfloor =\lfloor 2.25\rfloor=2\not\leq \lfloor 1.5\rfloor \lfloor 1.5\rfloor = 1\cdot 1 = 1$, so the inequality $a)$ doesnt hold for every $x,y\in\mathbb R^+$. The statement is false and citing a counter-example is enough to disprove it.

Comment: I meant 2.25, sorry, in my tired state I just did a mental addition.

Comment: @Marc-AndreLeclair If $x=x_1-r_1,y=y_1-r_2, (x_1,y_1\in\mathbb Z^+), 0\le r_1,r_2< 1$, then $\lceil x\rceil =x_1$ and $\lceil y\rceil =y_1$. The answer used the fact that $x_1,y_1\ge 1$ by stating $-r_2x_1-r_1y_1\le -r_2-r_1$, and the answer also used the fact that $r_1+r_2\ge 2\sqrt{r_1r_2}\iff (\sqrt{r_1}-\sqrt{r_2})^2\ge 0$ and the fact that $2\sqrt{r_1r_2}\ge r_1r_2$, which uses $0\le r_1r_2<1$.